# How to convert string to BSON

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, bson

I want to convert a string to BSON Obj to perform mongodb aggregate operation. All the queries will be stored in somewhere and now we have to convert string to BSON operation and show the result.

Lets say

```
var str = `[{"$match":{"tenantId":"TenantOne"}},{"$group":{"_id":{"referralType":"$referralType"},"value":{"$sum":1}}}]`
```

I've to convert to

```
var bsonobj = bson.A{
  bson.D{{
    Key: "$match", Value : bson.D{{
      Key : "tenantId" : Value: "TenantOne"
    }}
  }},
  bson.D{{
    Key: "$group", Value : bson.D{{
      Key : "_id" : Value: bson.D{{
        Key : "referralType" : Value: "$referralType"
      }},
      Key : "value" : Value: bson.D{{
        Key : "$sum" : Value: 1
      }}

    }}
  }}
}
```

I've tried [Golang MongoDB-Driver - Bson Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#Unmarshal)! I'm not able to use it properly.

Comment: And why are you trying to unmarshal it? Use [`Colleciton.Aggregate()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Aggregate) to execute it. You may pass `bsonobj` to it.

Comment: I'm not able to pass string to aggregate

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    var str = `[{"$match":{"tenantId":"TenantOne"}},{"$group":{"_id":{"referralType":"$referralType"},"value":{"$sum":1}}}]`
fmt.Println(str)
var bdoc interface{}
err := bson.UnmarshalExtJSON([]byte(str),true,&bdoc)
fmt.Println(bdoc)
fmt.Println(err)
```